# Entity framework with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have following method. I need to return var tynames by method so what would be the return type of the method will it be `List<string>` or something else and also what is the use of `FirstOrDefault()`.

Thanks in advance for your reply

```
public static List<string> AppType()
{
    var context = new Dll_IssueTracking.IssuTrackingEntities();// Object context defined in Dll_IssuTracking DLL

    var query = from c in context.ApplicationTypes//Query to find TypeNames
                select new { c.TypeName };
    var **TypeNames** = query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: The documentation for `FirstOrDefault<T>()` can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx.  It returns an object of type `T`.

Answer (score 1):

[`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) returns the first element found, or the default value (which is null in this case) if the query returned no results.
In this case the return value of the method should be `ApplicationType`:

```
public static ApplicationType AppType()   
{
    var context = new Dll_IssueTracking.IssuTrackingEntities(); // Object context defined in Dll_IssuTracking DLL

    var query = from c in context.ApplicationTypes //Query to find TypeNames
                    select new { c.TypeName };
    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Actually, it returns `default(T)` if there are no results.  It *will* return null in this particular case.

Comment: thanks..I have 3 typenames ( CUSTOM,STANDARD,NORMAL) can you please advise the code how to use this method and store values in a dropdownlist

Comment: @Raman that depends on what kind of application you're developing and what framework youre using. Please open a separate question and show what you have so far.

Comment: @Raman: But be cautious... Attempting to build an application piece by piece by asking questions on Stack Overflow isn't going to work.  Pick your battles; work for awhile until you get stuck, and then ask a question here.  Read MSDN or a book if you need detailed background information to complete your app.

Answer (score 0):

`FirstOrDefault` return first element in sequence, in this sample ApplicationTypes is your sequence or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.

Comment: Thanks Candie...one more thing how can i return var value like in above example I want to return Typenames

Answer (score 0):

`FirstOrDefault` is an extension method which looks something like this:

```
public T FirstOrDefault>T>(this IEnumerable<T> query)
{
    return query.Any() ? query.First() : default(T);
}
```

So, it returns the first element in the sequence if it is not empty, or the default of the type if the sequence is empty.

For Instance, if you have an `Enumerable<LinqEntity>`, then most likely `default(LinqEntity)` is `null`. If you had something like `Enumerable<int>` then `default(int)` is 0.